LVM Problems with lvresize showing no extents but there are extents available
I was trying to reduce the size of my Logical Volume.  However before doing so I forgot to do a filesystem check.  The original size of the logical volume was 403Gb I believe
[root@sysrescue ~]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgubuntu/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                vgubuntu
  LV UUID                SsWK0w-TKmI-TJ3F-8Dpc-amF3-KEXS-THlWRy
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2022-06-14 17:24:19 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                370.00 GiB
  Current LE             94720
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:1


[root@sysrescue ~]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/crypt1
  VG Name               vgubuntu
  PV Size               410.41 GiB / not usable <2.05 MiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              105065
  Free PE               10102
  Allocated PE          94963
  PV UUID               DZSReB-27GO-X7Kb-k5YS-m30d-qrYt-CDvyRU

Output from vgdisplay
[root@sysrescue ~]# vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vgubuntu
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  11
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               410.41 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              105065
  Alloc PE / Size       94963 / <370.95 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       10102 / 39.46 GiB
  VG UUID               oWzaaO-Obgi-VkXl-2o2h-eypj-4wfU-QSppqN

I'm trying to get the Logical volume back to 403G but its saying I don't have any free extents, however as you can see in vgdisplay there are 39.46Gb free or 10102 extents.
[root@sysrescue ~]# lvextend -L403G /dev/vgubuntu/root
  Insufficient free space: 8448 extents needed, but only 0 available

Because I forgot to run e2fsck before changing the logical volume size it now shows the partition table is likely corrupt.  And likewise resize2fs will not let me run without e2fsck completing.
[root@sysrescue ~]# e2fsck -f /dev/vgubuntu/root 
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 105906176 blocks
The physical size of the device is 96993280 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!

[root@sysrescue ~]# resize2fs /dev/vgubuntu/root 
resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Please run 'e2fsck -f /dev/vgubuntu/root' first.

Here is some more output kind of showing where the free space is that I want to reallocate to the logical volume.
[root@sysrescue ~]# pvs -v --segments /dev/mapper/crypt1
  PV                 VG       Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  Start  SSize LV     Start Type   PE Ranges                       
  /dev/mapper/crypt1 vgubuntu lvm2 u--  410.41g 39.46g      0 94720 root       0 linear /dev/mapper/crypt1:0-94719      
  /dev/mapper/crypt1 vgubuntu lvm2 u--  410.41g 39.46g  94720  8704            0 free                                   
  /dev/mapper/crypt1 vgubuntu lvm2 u--  410.41g 39.46g 103424   243 swap_1     0 linear /dev/mapper/crypt1:103424-103666
  /dev/mapper/crypt1 vgubuntu lvm2 u--  410.41g 39.46g 103667  1398            0 free 

                              

Does anyone know how to make the system actually realize I have free extents so I can resize the logical volume back to 403Gb? Seems I have 8704 extents available after /dev/vgubuntu/root according to the pvs -v --segments command.  I've searched through about 30 different posts and can't find any reference to this exact issue.
